# mock test class and test class for 2 classes

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, callout, httpcalloutmock

I have 2 class A and B.
A has code for Http Callout and from B we are calling A's class method which has callout code.
So should we write mock test class for A only or do we have to write mock test for both the classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can write one test class for class B and you need to include mock class where you need to specify the response inside mock class. Include this in test class and run this and confirm the code coverage. This is enough for deployment to Production.

Hope it answer your question!!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create single mock for Class A and then when you run your unit test for class B when it comes to HTTP Callout part in class A it will do that mock.

1) Class B calls method from Class A with Callout
2) When test comes to HTTP Callout it will implement the mock
3) Unit test continues as usual.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Franjo,When I am running the test class for class B, it is giving error as : Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts and this is becasue it is going to the callout class. Kindly help me to short it out.

Comment: You should have Test.StartTest & Test.StopTest somewhere in your test class. 
Try putting your mock callout between them. Something like this:

Test.StartTest 
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new YourHttpCalloutMockImpl());

//Your test code

Test.StopTest